# Creating dynamically multiple layers in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dynamic-layer

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.1 and Desktop 10.1 software.

I am publishing table from sqlserver to the ArcGIS server, that table (from sqlserver) is updating hourly, and the types are increasing.

I want to create dynamic layers according to type…( I am integrating those layers in Java script API)

So how should I do that? Any ideas/help will be highly appreciated..Thanks in advance : )

We have Desktop 10.1 and Server 10.1 only no ArcSDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little unclear what your scenario is, but if your saying that one column holds a type, say FRUIT_TYPE, and records are being added with additional types of fruit... it was [apples, oranges, grapes] now it's [apples, oranges, grapes, kumquats] you can't on the fly make new layers based on types. If you know the types ahead of time, you can make different layers based on a definition query.

What I think you want to do is symbolize a single layer using the column FRUIT_TYPE in the map document, see "Drawing a layer using categories" 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Drawing_a_layer_using_categories/00s50000003m000000/

Then you publish as a ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

If you made a the data a feature class, you could do some dynamic styling in javascript, maybe using a randomized color (or maybe define a long array of colors and pop the next one as needed) based on FRUIT_TYPE.

Then, do some javascript magic with popups or queries or identifytask, see my website for nice identify snippet http://www.spatialexception.org/posts/arcgis-javascript-identifytask-returns-scale-dependent-layers